# How to use float numbers with quartus megawizard ALTMULT_ACCUM(MAC)?

Tags: verilog, quartus

I am using the below mentioned module and testbench to use MAC megawizard in quartus, can anyone tell me how can I use floating point numbers for the same megawizard?

## Testbench

```
`timescale 1ns/1ps  
module projecttry2_tb;  
    reg [15:0] A, B;    
    wire [31:0] P;  
reg clk;  
projecttry2 M(.A(A),.B(B),.P(P),.clk(clk));  
initial    
       begin  
       clk = 1;  
       forever #25 clk = ~clk;  
       end
initial  
    begin  
    A=3008;  
    B=255;  
   #50  
    A=5859;  
    B=255;  
    #50  
    A=1133;  
    B=255;  
    #50  
    A=0;  
    B=0;  
    end  
endmodule
```

## Design Module

```
module projecttry2(A,B,P,clk);  
    input [15:0] A,B;  
    output [31:0] P;  
    input clk;  
mult_acc mult_acc_inst (  
    .clock0(clk),  
    .dataa(A),  
    .datab(B),  
    .result (P)  
    );  
endmodule
```

Comment: In your stimulus file you can replace `#50` with `@(posedge clk)` for a more robust testharness.

Answer (score 0):

ALTFP_MULT is available and documented on page 40 of [Floating-Point Megafunctions](https://www.altera.co.jp/ja_JP/pdfs/literature/ug/ug_altfp_mfug.pdf).

Comment: But our Professor has asked us to use MAC megafunction only @Morgan , is it even possible to use it for floating numbers?

Comment: I guess it is possible but a lot of work, have you looked at the floating point spec you will have multiple instances of MAC . https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point